# Visual Studio 2013 Unit Test Project throws SqlBuildTask error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I have a solution in `Visual Studio 2013` which contains a `SQL Server Database Project` and I have recently added a `Unit Test Project` which has 136 tests in it.  In `Test Explorer`, when I click on `Run All` to execute all of the tests, I receive the following error:

> 04018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.OnCreateCustomSchemaData(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2)' to access method 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components.Diagnostics.SqlTracer.ShouldTrace(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType)' failed.
>      at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.OnCreateCustomSchemaData(String filePath, Dictionary`2 referenceMetadata)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.CreateCustomSchemaData(String filePath, Dictionary`2 referenceMetadata)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.ProcessReferences(TaskLoggingHelper providedLogger, SqlTaskHost host, ErrorManager errors)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.LoadImpl(ITaskHost providedHost, TaskLoggingHelper providedLogger)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.Load(ITaskHost providedHost, TaskLoggingHelper providedLogger)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteLoadTaskHostStep()
>      at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteStep(Func`1 step)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

Comment: I know that it is not related to your question at all, but just in case you did not know that there is very good framework for tsql unit testing. It's name is tsqlt. Very easy to find on the web. It is not the spam, I am very satisfied by this product.

Comment: @sidux I may have to look into this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed by installing the latest version of SSDT, available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn864412

If the latest version of SSDT is already installed, try a repair installation.

Comment: Thank you.  That solved my problem.  At the time of this posting, I now have `SQL Server Data Tools v12.0.50730.0`.